# How do we insert data into a table?

Tags: azure-data-lake, u-sql

I'm attempting to insert data into a table:

```
@one_files = 
EXTRACT //all columns
FROM "/1_Main{suffixOne}.csv" 
USING Extractors.Text(delimiter : '|'); 

CREATE TABLE A1_Main (//all cols);

INSERT INTO A1_Main SELECT * FROM @one_files;
```

Within the same script I'm attempting to `SELECT` data:

```
@finalData = 
SELECT  //mycols
FROM A1_Main AS one;

OUTPUT @finalData
TO "/output/output.csv"
USING Outputters.Csv();
```

Here's the exception I get:

[image]

What am I doing wrong? How do I select from my table? Can we not insert and query in the same script?

Answer (score 1):

Some statements have restrictions on how they can be combined inside a script. For example, you cannot create a table and read from the same table in the same script, since the compiler requires that any input already physically exists at compile time of the query.

Check this:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/u-sql/concepts/scripts